I am trying to use JSON auth for JWT but its not starting
Error in the terminal
This is my first React JS project, I am creating an e-commerce store.I have data data/db.json its working fine when I use the command json-server data/db.json. But as shown in the picture when I try the "json-server data/db.json -m ./node_modules/json-server-auth" I get the error shown in the image.
Any solution?
Tried ChatGPT no solution got there.
I installed JSON-SERVER, JSON-AUTH and everything else required

Please post your error and code as text and not as an image.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
